# use Pushbots API on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, vb.net, pushbots

I finished setting up my Android hybrid app (webView app) with pushbots to receive push notification 
it work fine when i send it through their website dashboard.

the thing is i have a website programmed with VB.NET, Whenever i post something there i want it to send a notification to all android devices who have my app installed

you can send through Node.js, PHP, Mac terminal, etc 
https://pushbots.com/developer 
but there's nothing about ASP.NET :(

i really liked their service and the features it have, Is there a work around for it to work in ASP.NET or an alternative service like Pushbots ?

Answer (score 2):

i found unofficial .net API wrapper written by the community here: 
https://github.com/brandon-barker/PushBots.NET

i hope who have the same question find it useful